# Accessing objects from global environment that are directly passed to the function in a wrapper for ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environment, scoping

I'm generating a primitive wrapper for a `ggplot2` to generate histograms. As I've to generate a number of graphics it is easier for me to have a function that will go through all of the variables and spit out the desired graphs. My function code looks like that:

```
# Libs
require(ggplot2); require(ggthemes); require(grid)

GenerateHistogram <- function(histogramVariable, dataSet,
                              graphTitle = "Graph Title",
                              xAxis = "Count",
                              yAxis = "x axis title") {

  # Get the histogram value as indicator
  histVar <- get(paste(deparse(substitute(dataSet)), histogramVariable,
                       sep = "$"), envir = parent.frame(), 
                 inherits = TRUE)

  # Plot definition
  hist_plot <- ggplot(data = dataSet, aes_string(x = histogramVariable)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(histVar)), colour = 'red',
               size = 1) +
    ggtitle(graphTitle) +
    xlab(xAxis) +
    ylab(yAxis) +
    annotate("text", x = mean(histVar)*1.8,
             y = mean(histVar) - mean(histVar) * 0.1,
             label = paste("Mean:",round(mean(histVar),0)),
             colour = 'red') +
    theme_gdocs() +
    scale_colour_gdocs() +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90),
          plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5),"mm"))

  # Return
  return(hist_plot)
}
```

when I attempt to run the code:

```
> data(mtcars)
> GenerateHistogram(histogramVariable = "disp", dataSet = mtcars,
+                   graphTitle = "Disp", xAxis = "X title", yAxis = "y Title")
```

I receive the following error:

> ```
> Error in get(paste(deparse(substitute(dataSet)), histogramVariable, sep = "$"),  : 
>   object 'mtcars$disp' not found
> Called from: get(paste(deparse(substitute(dataSet)), histogramVariable, sep = "$"), 
>     envir = parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE)
> ```

It appears that the problem is with the statement:

```
  histVar <- get(paste(deparse(substitute(dataSet)), histogramVariable,
                       sep = "$"), envir = parent.frame(),
                 inherits = TRUE)
```

## Task

I want to achieve the following:

1. Pass arguments to the `ggplot` to generate the chart; `aes_string`
   appears to be a suitable solution and this part is working
2. Source the argument by name from the environment where the function is called so I can do different things with that variable such as calculating values for bells and whistles that I'm adding to the histogram

   2.1 I may further develop this function by adding mechanism to wisely calculate bins sizes or to modify the values, having values accessible as a numeric vector will be extremely handy

### Objectives

So in a word, the function has two simple objectives:

- Work as a wrapper for `ggplot` histogram - *achieved* with use of the `aes_string`
- Provide scope for additional calculation on the histogram variable, *presently outstanding*

---

## Edits

Following very useful comments, I tried:

```
  # Get the histogram value as indicator
  relevant_column <- histogramVariable
  histVar <- dataSet[,relevant_column]
```

which seemed to produce the error:

> `Error in mean(histVar) : object 'histVar' not found`

Comment: Your dataset and variable are already inside your function environment. Is there a reason you're not doing `dataset[,histogramVariable]` instead of the `get-from-parent-environment`-approach you currently have?

Comment: Thanks for showing the interest in my post. I'm guessing is that the problem is with how I pass my variable. For the purpose of the `aes_string` the variable is passed as `"variable"` not as `variable`  If I do `dataset[,histogramVariable]` it will be `dataset[,"histogramVariable"]`, which won't work, I presume, or I'm missing something?

Comment: [I'm working on it]. Dataframe columns can be accessed by strings (df[,"a"]), but also by variables if the variable is a string. so if you'd do `b <- 'a'; df[,b]` you could access column a.

Comment: @Heroka This may be a solution instead of faffing around with `get`, environments and scoping rules thanks very much for your contribution. I will experiment, why don't you make it answer if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are multiple ways to solve this that don't involve scoping. Here is one, I generated an additional dataframe inside the function with contains the mean and passed that to geom_vline. There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but this way gives you a lot of control and a way to do your own calculations (less black box).

I have removed all of your additional formatting, to focus on the solution.

```
GenerateHistogram <- function(histogramVariable="disp", dataSet=mtcars,
                              graphTitle = "Graph Title",
                              xAxis = "Count",
                              yAxis = "x axis title") {


  #generate additional/summarizing data
  #this gives you a dataframe you can feed to geom_vline,
  #so more control and no scoping issues
  add_data <- data.frame(mean=mean(dataSet[,histogramVariable]))

  # Plot definition
  hist_plot <- ggplot(data = dataSet, aes_string(x = histogramVariable)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    geom_vline(data=add_data, aes(xintercept=mean))

    # Return
    return(hist_plot)
}
```

Edit: I did some more looking around, because while working this solution is a bit laborious. The issue here is with a string as variable, so for the `geom_vline` without additional data, you could do:

```
geom_vline(aes_string(xintercept=sprintf("mean(%s)",histogramVariable)))
```

Comment: Thank very much, smart solution!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an edit because I had the 'this should be possible without additional data'-frustration.

Comment: Thanks very much, very useful solution. I may fiddle a little with adjusting bin widths and producing some other gadgets so I do not mind the additional data.